# Reusing HTML between the server and client sides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing a web site. On the server-side I'm using python (and Genshi) to manipulate/generate the HTML. But I find myself manipulating **the same** kind of HTML fragments on the client-side, using Javascript.

Let me show you an example. Suppose I have an editable list of items:

```
<form .... >
<ul>
  <li id="i1">Name: <input type="text" name="i1" value="Item 1" /> <a href="#">[del]</a></li>
  <li id="i2">Name: <input type="text" name="i2" value="Item 2" /> <a href="#">[del]</a></li>
</ul>
<a id="addnew" href="#">[new]</a>
</form>
```

Note: The `[new]` anchor dynamically adds new items to the form. It doesn't (have to) make any request to the server.

Both the server and the client have to know this "template" (pseudo-code):

```
<li id="${id}">Name: <input type="text" name="${name}" value="${val} " /> <a href="#">[del]</a></li>
```

The server has to know it to create the initial HTML list, and the client has to know it to allow the users to add and remove items, using the anchors.

**What would you say are the best-practices to improve reuse in a scenario like this?**

---

Some approaches that I already know I'd like to avoid:

- Creating the initial list using javascript. I'm trying to use javascript to improve some parts of the user interaction only
- Using a template language that I can somehow reuse between the client and the server is not an option because I'm stuck with Genshi for now
- Generating Javascript on the server side. Tried this before, and it's a pain to debug, due to the extra level of indirection

Comment: Are you using a framework on the client side? jQuery Prototype or another?

Comment: Using jQuery on the client side.

Comment: I would like to find a more general approach to the issue... but a jQuery-specific solution would be ok in this case, if that's an option

Comment: Maybe I'm getting something wrong cause I can't see the problem... First, I don't get why the client needs to know the data in order to create a new item. Second, in order to delete an item, you can use, for example, `$(this).parent().attr('id')` to know the id of the item.

Comment: @scumah The client needs to know the template for an item because it will dynamically change the page, to add new items.

Comment: @scumah I've just updated the example, you may have got the previous version earlier. I hope it's clearer now what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about store the HTML in a hidden div with some initial placeholders, use JavaScript to copy that into the visible piece of the UI and replace the place holders with your AJAX response. The response could be JSON (Key/Value pair list).

Comment: Well, I must say it has crossed my mind... but it kinda perverts the HTML markup (the hidden HTML makes no sense there from a "HTML document" point of view)

Comment: If the best solution involves making additional requests to the server, I guess I'd rather directly return only the html fragment already "filled in" with the values. Feels like a lot of work for something that ought to be simple though...

Comment: Hiding HTML in a document is in no way wrong or perverted. Honestly it's the AJAX request themselves that take the longest, not the relatively small file size. If it's too much work to justify the small performance gain I would just get back the HTML fragment from the server.

Comment: Speed is not a motivation for me right now (despite it's importance)... I'm leaning towards cloning from a hidden div, but I can avoid the ajax request in this case, as I don't need to fill it with any values that I don't already have in the page yet.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably when you add a new item, you are making an Ajax call to send the data to the server?  One approach would be to return an HTML fragment as the response to that call.  It's a bit of a hack, but less so than generating JavaScript.

A more RESTful way of doing it would be to return a `201 Created` response with a canonical `Location` header for the created item.  Your JavaScript would then make a request for the resource with an `Accept` header specifying a custom media type that represents the HTML fragment.  This separates presentation from business logic, so, for example, you could add items from more than one page requiring different types of HTML fragment.

Comment: The goal was that the user could add more "item" lines to the form. No ajax calls would be needed for that... 
But the solution to fetch the html fragment from the server is valid nonetheless. I had already mentioned it to @Nick as a possibility, although I was hoping to find a simpler solution. This solution requires a new kind of request to be created on the server for this purpose only...

Comment: In that case, I'd be more inclined to clone one of the existing lines and wipe the form values.

Comment: Or another option would be to make an empty clone on page load that you can generate new lines from at will.

Comment: I've been experimenting with having a reusable "clone". Unfortunately, it's not guaranteed that the list always has items in the beginning, and in such cases I would have nothing to clone from. 

Of course, as @Nick suggested, I can use a hidden item, that I would use exclusively as a [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern](prototype) to clone from. I still think it's not a completely satisfactory solution though, as it does pollute the markup with non-contents...

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a long shot, but you could investigate [genshi2js](http://hg.codeflow.org/genshi2js/summary). It claims to compile a subset of genshi templates into javascript functions (similar to Google's soy templates). Unfortunately it seems to be an abandoned project. The main link for it is 404, but I was able to find the mercurial repository at the link above, and it's last activity was in 2008.

The best solution to this problem in general is to use the same template system and have both a JS and server-side implementation. (That's also the idea behind Google soy templates--java and js implementations.)

Comment: Yes, as much as it looks interesting, genshi2js doesn't seem to be ready. Thanks for the pointer though.